How to implement Mask Calling using REST API or Python SDK?
How to implement Mask Calling using REST API or Python SDK?
I want to implement the solution shown in below image. Are there are any API, SDK or service, platform available to implement this solution?

The mask number should be valid for specific time.

Is this phone number masking? Either way this doesn't feel like an appropriate question for Stackoverflow as it will either lead to off-site resources or opinion-based answers since it feels very broad in nature and isn't focused on a particular programming problem with code you are currently developing.
